# UISearchBar text color when used in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i'm trying to change a UISearchbar text color in iOS7 app. (i want the text to be white).
the search bar is attached to a searchDisplay controller.

i have tried many options, including this one:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], [FVRNavigationBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

also tried `setTintColor:`, and `setBarTintColor:`. Nothing works.
Note, this solutions does work when the search bar is not attached to a displayController.

FYI, not that i think it matters, but i use a background image for my search bar.
in addition, the searchbar is placed in my navigationBar.

here is my code:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], [FVRNavigationBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 52)];
[_searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[IMAGE(@"searchBarBg") resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_displayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_displayController.delegate = self;
_displayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

I'd appreciate anyones help. thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. The searchdisplaycontroller has hijacked the text color for search field...